# How to format python string with multiple characters as pading part

Tags: python, string, templates, format

This is all good to pad a single character:

```
>>> '{:{pad}>{num}}'.format('12345',num='10', pad='a')
aaaaa12345
```

However, how to print out `abcab12345`, by using 'abc' as padding characters?

this is bad:

```
>>> '{:{pad}>{num}}'.format('12345',num='10', pad='abc')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-85d5680ad88a> in <module>()
----> 1 '{:{pad}>{num}}'.format('hello',num='10', pad='abc')

ValueError: Invalid format specifier
```

I like the mini format language in python3 BTW ;-)

Comment: I don't really understand what is the desired output, would you mind expanding the question a bit?

Comment: @Netwave i think the desired output is `abcab12345`. That is pad with more that one character

Answer (score 0):

You should concatenate the `format` operations (**TIP**: you need to ward your `{}` with doubles `{{}}` for each format nesting level):

```
baseFmtStr = "'{{{{:{{pad}}>{num}}}}}'"
resultStr = baseFmtStr.format(num=10).format(pad='-').format(12345)
```

This let us to result `'-----12345'`

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/repls/EasyOlivedrabExtensions)